# Relation between stirling numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

Is there a relation between $$ \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n}{n-2} $$

and $$ \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{n-1}{n-3} $$

Like the first one can be obtained from the second one by adding something?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419617/stirling-numbers-with-k-n-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) satisfy a somewhat Pascal-like [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation):

$${{n+1}\brace k}=k{n\brace k}+{n\brace{k-1}}\;.$$

In particular, then,

$${n\brace{n-2}}=(n-2){{n-1}\brace{n-2}}+{{n-1}\brace{n-3}}\;.\tag{1}$$

It’s easy to check that

$${{n-1}\brace{n-2}}=\binom{n-1}2\;,$$

so $(1)$ becomes

$${n\brace{n-2}}=(n-2)\binom{n-1}2+{{n-1}\brace{n-3}}\;.$$